# How to pass an attribute from servlet to HTML page, then to another servlet?

Tags: java, html, servlets, attributes

First servlet has the following:

```
    request.setAttribute("registereduser",registereduser);
    request.setAttribute("password",password);

    RequestDispatcher  rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("login.html");
    rd.include(request,response);
```

The page login.html has a form:

```
<form action="LoginServlet" method="get">
    ...
</form>
```

But registereduser and password are not actually used in login.html. How do I pass them to LoginServlet? To clarify -- LoginServlet is supposed to have:

```
    String registereduser=request.getParameter("registereduser");
    String password=request.getParameter("password");
```

Tsolakp suggested to use hidden input field. So if I put into form within login.html:

```
 <input type="hidden" id="registereduser" name="registereduser" value=...>
```

what exactly should be the value?

Comment: You can either put them into the session or embed the values as hidden inputs in the form and pass to servlet as request parameters.

Comment: your question is not clear

Answer (score -1):

You don't pass data from servlet to HTML, rather JSP.

```
 request.setAttribute("registereduser",registereduser);
    request.setAttribute("password",password);
    RequestDispatcher  rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp");
    rd.forward(request,response);
```

In login.jsp

```
 <form action="LoginServlet" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="user" value=<%=request.getAttribute("registereduser")%>">
    </form>
```

In LoginServlet

```
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String userName = request.getParameter("user");

    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer does not show how to pass `registereduser` and `password` back to servlet from HTML form.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use JSP scriptlet tags inside a plain html page. **You need a .jsp for this.**

You can pass values from a servlet to a JSP page like this:

SERVLET:

```
request.setAttribute("registereduser",registereduser);
request.setAttribute("password",password);

RequestDispatcher  rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp");
rd.include(request,response);
```

JSP LOGIN PAGE WITH SCRIPTLET:

```
 <form action="LoginServlet" method="get">
 <input type="text" name="user" value="<%=request.getAttribute("registereduser")%>">
</form>
```

JSP LOGIN PAGE WITH EL:

```
 <form action="LoginServlet" method="get">
 <input type="text" name="user" value="${registereduser}">
</form>
```